# Showing that the span of the intersection of two spans is contained in their intersection

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: Let $W_1$ $=$ $\operatorname{Span}(S_1)$ and $W_2$ $=$ $\operatorname{Span}(S_2)$ be subspaces of a vector space.

Show that $W_1$ $\cap$ $W_2$ $\supset$ $\operatorname{Span}(S_1 \cap S_2)$.

And how do you show that $W_1\cap W_2\ne \operatorname{Span}(S_1\cap S_2)$ in general?

Attempt:

We are trying to show that $W_1$ $\cap$ $W_2$ contains $\operatorname{Span}(S_1 \cap S_2)$.

Don't even know how to approach this question beyond the logic and please correct me if I'm wrong. Any vector $v$ $\in$ $\operatorname{Span}(S_1 \cap S_2)$ is also in $W_1$ and $W_2$

Comment: Let $x\in\langle S_1\cap S_2\rangle$. Then, $x$ is generated by elements of $S_1\cap S_2$, i.e., $x=\displaystyle\sum_{v_i\in S_1\cap S_2}a_iv_i$. Now, since $S_1\cap S_2\subseteq S_1,S_2$, we see that $x\in\langle S_1\rangle=W_1$ and $x\in\langle S_2\rangle=W_2$ (just set the spanning coefficients to $a_i$ when the $v_i\in S_1$ (analogously $S_2$) and $0$ otherwise). Thus, $x\in W_1\cap W_2$ showing $\langle S_1\cap S_2\rangle\subseteq W_1\cap W_2$

Answer (score 2):

Your question has actually been answered in a comment. As for a conterexample concerning the case of equality, I can provide the following.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, consider $S_1=\Bigg\{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right)\Bigg\}$ and
$S_2=\Bigg\{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right),
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
1\\
\end{array}
\right)\Bigg\}$.

Let $W_1$, $W_2$ be respectively the span of $S_1$, $S_2$. If we think of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a three dimensional space with axis $x$,$y$,$z$, then $W_1$ is the plane $(Oxy)$ whereas $W_2$ is the plane $(Oxz)$. The intersection of $W_1$ and $W_2$ is the $x$ axis. Formally, $$W_1\cap W_2=\Bigg\{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
\lambda\\
0\\
0\\
\end{array}
\right),
\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\Bigg\}$$

However, $S_1\cap S_2=\emptyset$, so that $\operatorname{Span}(S_1\cap S_2)=\{0\}$.

Hence, we have $\operatorname{Span}(S_1\cap S_2) \subsetneq W_1\cap W_2$.

Comment: i think you made some errors in the end. edited post. lemme know if i'm wrong please.

Comment: Dear @BCLC, thank you for the edits, in particular regarding the span of $S_1 \cap S_2$. You are perfectly right, it is $\{0\}$. However, I do not understand why you modified the last line. I believe there was nothing wrong with my previous writing : we do have $\mathrm{Span}(S_1\cap S_2) \subsetneq W_1 \cap W_2$. That is, the space $W_1 \cap W_2$ contains $\mathrm{Span}(S_1\cap S_2)$ strictly. Have you perhaps mixed the symbols $\subsetneq$ and $\not \subset$ ?

Comment: Suzet you're welcome and thanks for the feedback. yeah that's the mix up. damn those people who use $\subset$ for inclusive XD